# preact-cli has high severity vulnerabilities and npm audit fix runs in circles (3.0.5 <-> 2.2.1)

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, preact, preact-cli

I'm setting up a preact project with preact-cli:

```
npx --version # 7.4.0
npx preact-cli create typescript frontend
```

This tells me:

```
...
added 1947 packages, and audited 1948 packages in 31s

129 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

3 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
✔ Done!
```

3 high security vulnerabilities after just running the default setup!?
That doesn't sound very reassuring.

```
npm audit fix

...
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install preact-cli@2.2.1, which is a breaking change
```

Ok, so apparently npm fix wants to downgrade preact-cli. Let's go then:

```
npm audit fix --force

...

fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install preact-cli@3.0.5, which is a breaking change
node_modules/preact-cli/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/yargs-parser
node_modules/preact-cli/node_modules/yargs-parser
  yargs  4.0.0-alpha1 - 12.0.5 || 14.1.0 || 15.0.0 - 15.2.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of os-locale
  Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs-parser
  node_modules/preact-cli/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/yargs
  node_modules/preact-cli/node_modules/yargs
    preact-cli  1.0.0 - 3.0.0-next.3
    Depends on vulnerable versions of extract-text-webpack-plugin
    Depends on vulnerable versions of url-loader
    Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs
    node_modules/preact-cli
    webpack  2.1.0-beta.8 - 4.0.0-alpha.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs
    node_modules/preact-cli/node_modules/webpack
      extract-text-webpack-plugin  2.0.0-beta.0 - 3.0.2
      Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack
      node_modules/preact-cli/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin
      webpack-dev-server  2.0.0-beta - 3.10.3
      Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack
      Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs
      node_modules/preact-cli/node_modules/webpack-dev-server

17 vulnerabilities (7 low, 8 moderate, 2 high)
```

Ah yes, downgrading to 2.2.1 introduces new vulnerabilities. They can be solved by undoing the downgrade and going back up to 3.0.5.

This is a circle, npm audit fix --force just switches back and forth between the 3.0.5 and 2.2.1 versions of preact-cli.

**Some context:**
This seems to be a known [issue](https://github.com/preactjs/preact-cli/issues/1514).

Answer (score 0):

Late here (already closed on the CLI repo) but for context, `2.2.1` is a few years old now, and the dependency was a build time one. There's no risk for build time dependencies, especially this one, as it just existed to report changes in your built bundle size.

Always look at what `npm audit` is actually complaining about. If it's something that's build-time only, you can ignore it.